# How to update approved from 0 to 1 in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

Hi following are my relations.

SubmitApplication.php

```
public function requisition()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Requisition::class);
}
```

Requisition.php

```
public function submitApplication()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubmitApplication::class);
}
```

My blade

```
<form class="btn-group" action="{{ route('requisitions.update', ['id' => $requisition->id]) }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">تایید</button>
</form>
```

RequisitionController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, SubmitApplication $submitApplication)
{
    $submitApplication->approved = 1;
    $submitApplication->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

For requisitions table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('requisitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('school_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    });
}
```

For submit_applications table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('submit_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('requisition_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('school_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('approved')->nullable(true);
        $table->string('application')->nullable(true);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('requisition_id')->references('id')->on('requisitions');
        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    });
}
```

When I click approved button. it added. id do not want add

[image: Databasse]

Maybe am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to retrieve the data before updating? It seems that in your RequisitionController.php, you did not retrieve the data and you directly save it.

Answer (score 0):

In your RequisitionController.php, you must retrieve first the model before using save method.

```
$submitApplication = SubmitApplication ::find($request['id']);
```